# How to correct MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

I need to create rest style web service with one of the methods conforming to this type of URI.

> api/v1/{controller}/{device}/registrations/{id}

```
    public class DevicesController : ApiController
    {
        public void Get(string device, string id)
        {
        }
    }
```

Seems like I'm missing something out there, any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Can you post your actual routing config? What is your actual problem your controller is not being hit, exception, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, must have been doing something wrong before.  This seems to work fine.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("PassApi",
"api/v1/{controller}/{device}/registrations/{id}",
new { controller = "Devices" });
```